# Is there a way to speed up querying latitude-longitude of postcodes on a large dataframe using pgeocode?

Tags: python, pandas, latitude-longitude, postal-code

I have a dataframe of around 100k rows with postcodes and country codes. I would like to get the latitude and longitude of each location and save it in two new columns. I have a working code on a sample of the dataframe (e.g. 100 rows), but running it on all dataframe takes so long (>1hour). I am new to Python and suspect, there should be a faster way to do so in terms of:

1. For a given `postcode` and `country_code`, I am querying twice, once for latitude and once for longitude. I am pretty convinced that I should not do that (i.e. I can make a single query per line and create latitude and longitude columns accordingly).
2. The way I define the function `get_lat(pcode, country)` and `get_long(pcode, country)` and apply on the dataframe is not efficient.

An example of my code is below.

```
import pgeocode
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#Sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'postcode':['3011','3083','3071','2660','9308','9999'], 'country_code': ['NL','NL','NL','BE','BE','DE']})

#There are blank postcodes and postcodes that pgeocode cannot return any value, so I am using try-except (e.g. last row in sample dataframe): 
#function to get latitude 
def get_lat(pcode, country):
    try:
        nomi = pgeocode.Nominatim(country)
        x = nomi.query_postal_code(pcode).latitude
        return x
    except:
        return np.NaN

#function to get longitude
def get_long(pcode, country):
    try:
        nomi = pgeocode.Nominatim(country)
        x = nomi.query_postal_code(pcode).longitude
        return x
    except:
        return np.NaN

#Find and create new columns for latitude-longitude based on postcode (ex: 5625) and country of postcode (ex: NL)
df['latitude'] = np.vectorize(get_lat)(df['postcode'],df['country_code'])
df['longitude'] = np.vectorize(get_long)(df['postcode'],df['country_code'])
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution, I downloaded the txt files from this website: http://download.geonames.org/export/zip/

After downloading the files, it is simply a matter of importing the txt file and joining. It is much faster but static, i.e. you use a snapshot of the postcode database at an earlier time.

Another advantage is that you can check the files and inspect the format of the postcodes. While using `pgeocode`, it is harder to keep track of the accepted postcode format and understand why queries return null.

Comment: nice approach, was having the same issue